# Доброгласен, износящ

Tags: этимология, синонимы, славянизмы

О священнике коломенском, будущем архимандрите Михаиле: «Был голосист, глас имея доброгласен, износящ».

При том, что *Износить* = выносить, приносить (в жертву, отдавать), произносить, производить и т. п., какое современное слово могло бы заменить его?

Answer (score 1):

**Износящий - это произносящий,** например: Никто Духом Божиим говорящий не говорит того, что противно вере во Христа Всякий износящий из уст своих полезные к созиданию ближнего слова, из благого сокровища сердца своего износит их, по слову Господа (Мф.).

Голос износящ - это, скорее всего, голос **выразительный, колоритный, красочный**.